# firebase login and signup help in kivy Python code

Tags: firebase-authentication, kivy, kivymd

i have it so when entering the info into the signup input boxes and hitting the submit button.. it saves into the realtimedb in firebase auth.. the problem comes when i want to authenticate a user and then if the user isn't in the db i need to display a message
basically my code is...

loginsignup.py

```
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
auth = firebase.auth()

class MyFirebaseSignup:
    def sign_up(self, username, email, password, login_message=None):
        try:
            user = auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
            data = {"email": email, "password": password, "idToken": True}
            info = auth.get_account_info(user["idToken"])
            auth.send_email_verification(user["idToken"])
            password = data.get("password")
            print("Successfully created account")
            #Go to login.kv page
        except:
            print("Invalid")
            #Display Error message from firebase id: signup_message (signup.kv)
    pass

class MyFirebaseLogin():
    def Login(self, email, password):
        try:
            login = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
            info = auth.get_account_info(login["idToken"])
            print("The data of text field is : ",self.root.ids.data.login)
            print("Successfully Logged in")
            #Go to profile.kv page
        except:
            print("Invalid")
            #Display Error message from firebase id: login_message (login.kv)
    pass

.....
    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("main.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("signup.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("login.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("forgotpassword.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("profile.kv"))
        self.my_firebasesignup = MyFirebaseSignup()
        self.my_firebaselogin = MyFirebaseLogin()
        #self.firebaseForgotPassword = MyFirebaseForgotPassword()
        return screen_manager

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LoginSignup().run()
```

signup.kv

```
<SignupScreen>:
MDScreen:
    name: "signup"
    id: signup
    MDFloatLayout:
            text: "Create a new account"
        MDLabel:
            id: signup_message
            color: (1,0,0,1)
        MDFloatLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: login_username
                hint_text: "Username"
                multiline: False
        MDFloatLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: login_email
                hint_text: "Email"
                multiline: False
        MDFloatLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: login_password
                hint_text: "Password"
                multiline: False
                password: True
        Button:
            text: "SIGNUP"
            on_release:
                print("Sign up", login_email.text, login_password.text)
                app.my_firebasesignup.sign_up(login_username.text,login_email.text,login_password.text)

        MDLabel:
            text: "Already have an account?"
        MDTextButton:
            text: "Sign in"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.manager.current = "login"
```

login.kv

```
<LoginScreen>:
MDScreen:
    name: "login"
    id: login
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDLabel:
            text: "Sign in to continue"
        MDLabel:
            id: login_message
            color: (1,0,0,1)
            TextInput:
                id: login_email
                hint_text: "Email"
                multiline: False
        MDFloatLayout:
            TextInput:
                id: login_password
                hint_text: "Password"
                multiline: False
                password: True
        Button:
            text: "LOGIN"
            on_release:
                print("Sign in", login_email.text, login_password.text)
                app.my_firebaselogin.Login(login_email.text,login_password.text)
        MDTextButton:
            text: "Forgot Password?"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                #root.manager.current = "forgotpassword"
        MDLabel:
            text: "Don't have an account?"
        MDTextButton:
            text: "Sign up"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.manager.current = "signup"
```

i cant find in any of the tutorials online how to display the errors using a label or if successful to move forward to a new page

Basically how do i:

Once signed up successfully, then go to login.kv page ... if my other buttons on other screens to go on release, root.manager.current = "login"

If there is an error in the Signup details, display those details in the signup_message on the signup.kv page?

I took out the formatting, etc... and im sure it is so simple.. but i cant figure it out
once i know how to do it once... il be able to do it on the others, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using **label **or** MDLabel** . Your need to set **text: ''** in the kv file and assign an **id** with it and using the **id** update it on runtime using a defined function in the main function.

*using this function you can update the error message on the runtime*

```
def signup(self):
    # Code for signup process...
    if signup_successful:
        self.root.manager.current = "login"
    else:
        self.root.ids.signup_message.text = "Error: {}".format(error_message)
```

*in the kv file assign **text:''** for handling it with the function*

```
<SignupScreen>:
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDLabel:
            id: signup_message   # Assign an ID to the MDLabel
            text: ""
        # Other UI components...
```

With the above changes, if the signup is successful, the application will navigate to the "login" screen. If there is an error in the signup details, the error message will be displayed in the "signup_message" label on the "signup.kv" page.